# How to fetch WordPress api with all the styling not just plain text with React

Tags: reactjs, wordpress-rest-api

So I want to use React to fetch blog posts from WordPress, but when I do so, all the styling is lost and I get only JSON plain text which is neither formated nor styles with h1, no images, and vice versa, what is the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Using [graphql](https://www.wpgraphql.com/) you can query enqueuedStylesheets over posts

```
    query MyQuery {
      posts {
         nodes {
                  enqueuedStylesheets {
                     nodes {
                           src
                     }
                  }
        }
      }
    }
```

And you can add styles to your react page with [react-helmet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet).

```
<Helmet>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
 </Helmet>
```